# It's okay to take a break from Skeptics

Tags: discussion

Some of us (myself included) need this reminder from time to time.

Sometimes a topic pops up that heat us up. Things like elections, the pandemic, vaccination, etc, etc. And, we are passionate folks - we want to see the stuff cleared up and the misconceptions gone. But, sometimes, those topics upset us, and even with all of our willpower we still end up feeling heated and wanting to prove others "wrong" and clear things up with a fiery passion...

This sometimes is good, sometimes it isn't.

With the current situation on Israel/Gaza going on, we often stumble upon topics we want to see addressed. We want to leave that heated comment, we want to scream on top of our lungs that X side is bad/wrong and that Y side is good/right and...

And this isn't the place for that. We all have things we're passionate about, that are dear to us. But we are all human.

And humans need to take a break when things get stressful or heated.

If the current topics are difficult to handle, take a break. Have a rest, visit some other communities for a few days. Go hang in chat instead of using the main site. Don't fret, don't stress. Getting upset with people on the internet isn't worth it.

Don't be afraid to take a break.

---

And, for the mods: thanks for keeping things civil. I have no idea how much work you guys are doing on the background, but I'm sure things are probably quite hectic.

Answer (score 10):

In this time of need, we also have the ignored questions feature by our side (specifically the right side):

[image: Ignored tags input]

You can use this to make questions you don't want to see less prominent or hide them if you don't want to see them. For these current events, try `israel palestine 2023-israel-hamas-war hamas`. I've been paying attention to see if anything needs to be retagged with this in mind.

This way you could ask or answer questions on lighter subjects (those breatharians!) without having to see questions you don't want to.

Jokes aside, I hope everyone is doing the best you can in life. It's not easy.